# Replace and update columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Table

```
    A     B     C     D     E
1  Jan   Feb  Mar    Apr   Jun
2   24   32    64    54     45
3   66   76    76    76     87
4   45   65    84    67     23
```

the last 3 columns should automatically update in another column as

Last 3 moths data

```
    AN        AO       AP
1   Month1  Month2   Month3
2     64     54        45
3     76     76        87
4     84     67        23
```

If I add another column in the first table as july in columns `F`. Then it should automatically replace the data in Month3 in second table and month3 data sholud move to month2 and month2 to month1.

```
=IF(AN2="",AL2,IF(AO2="",AM2,IF(AP2="",AN2,IF(AQ2="",AO2,IF(AQ2<>"",AP2,IF(AP2<>"",AO2,IF(AO2<>"",AN2,IF(AN2<>"",AM2,""))))))))
```

The formula is simlar to the another columns.

Comment: So, you want always last 3 months data to 2nd table from 1st table?

Comment: Yes, It should automatically update whenever I add new columsn to the first table.

Answer (score 3):

With any version of Excel:

You can detect where the columns end using many methods - the simplest is using `Count`.

Enter the following into the top left of your result table:

`=INDEX(2:2,,COUNT(2:2)-2)`

This counts the number of cells with data in, and returns the data from that numbered column (offset to the left by 2). In the next cell to its right, change the `-2` to `-1`. In the last cell, change the `-1` to `-0` or remove that part entirely.

Then copy the cells down to match your source table.

Answer (score 2):

If you have ***Excel-365*** then use below formula.

```
=INDEX(A1:Z4,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A4)),SEQUENCE(1,3,MAX(IF(A1:Z1<>"",COLUMN(A1:Z1),""))-2))
```

If you don't have `Excel-365` then use below formula then drag down and across as required.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$Z$4,ROW($A1),MAX(IF($A$1:$Z$1<>"",COLUMN($A$1:$Z$1),""))-3+COLUMN(A$1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have ms365, try to use `FILTER()`, for example:

[image]

Formula in `G1`:

```
=FILTER(Table1[#All],COLUMN(Table1[#Headers])>COLUMNS(Table1[#Headers])-3)
```

---

If you *add* columns:

[image]

---

If you *remove* columns:

[image]